# PowerShell command to get installed application/software version

Tags: windows, powershell, version, get-wmiobject

I need to read product version from control panel for specific application. I'm using this command till now.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "Name like 'ISASmaartHub'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty
```

after upgrading my system to Windows 11 it is throwing this exception -

```
Select-Object : Missing an argument for parameter 'ExpandProperty'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
At line:1 char:82
+ ...  -Filter "Name like 'ISASmaartHub'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Can anyone please suggest which command I should use to read the version of an application on Windows 11 system.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would not have worked on Win10 either. Change `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version`

Comment: As a tip I can give you: don't use win32_product, it's broken (very slow and it can actually reset software settings in some rare cases because of the consistency check). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-software-installations?view=powershell-7.2 for more info

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to get the version now using Get-CimInstance as well as Get-WmiObject. As suggested will go with Get-CimInstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Prefer using `Get-CimInstance` over `Get-WmiObject` for new applications, as WMI is being deprecated.
2. For WMI\CIM, operator LIKE uses WQL language and should have a `%` sign as a mark for `Any symbols`. [WQL Like Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/like-operator)
3. `Select -ExpandProperty smth` means from this big object select only value of `smth` property. This means, property name MUST present.

---

Working Example for product named `1C`:

```
Get-CimInstance -Filter 'NAME LIKE "%1C%"' -ClassName 'Win32_Product' | 
    Select -ExpandProperty 'Version'
```